# DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Template::Handlers::Erubis is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Template::Handlers::Erubis is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.2. Switch to ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::Erubi instead.

The warning clearly explained to Switch to ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::Erubi instead.
OK But how
What I did is replaced gem 'haml-rails' with 'haml' but still warning

It's happened in Rails 5.1.0 rc1 with Ruby 2.4.1

Comment: This is only a warning for the gem itself, you don't have to do anything. It will be sorted out in time for Rails 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported as a bug.
Now its fixed [here](https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/895#issuecomment-294901671)

Comment: It was reported by someone else (and fixed) 3 months ago.

Comment: Yes but this is another issue #895 (comment) 3 days ago. That why I asked and someone down vote. Then I went to github and  This bug fixed by k0kubun . You right the first bug was closed.

Answer (score 3):

This warning should be gone with next released version of Haml (5.0.0): https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/9cc8b13e0b2c383f1a3000d9069d3fedc4377d2d/CHANGELOG.md

> - Support Rails 5.1 Erubi template handler.

Answer (score 2):

Extended @Sergio answer. To remove warnings you need to:

```
 bundle update haml-rails
```

If you get some dependency error remove 'version guard' in you `Gemfile` file for haml-rails

```
  gem 'haml-rails' # add version guard just after update
```